# Where is SDL Tridion Connector for ADAM located in installation media

Tags: 2013, ecl

The documentation for SDL Tridion connector 1.0 describe a procedure for running the connector for ADAM installer. However i am not able to locate the installer on media that i am suppose to run. I am using Tridion 2013 SP1. The external content library is already installed.
The link that i am following is [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDLTridion_ADAMConnector10&lang=en-US&docid=concept_D82DE82799A84315AF8B84027D9458C2&query=adam#addHistory=true&filename=ADAM_Installer.xml&docid=task_6395FEBD6797437384056B02B896E316&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_6395FEBD6797437384056B02B896E316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question you should be asking here, it is one which you should ask to Customer Support in my opinion.

But I'll attempt to give you an answer anyways, the SDL Tridion Connector for ADAM is licensed separately and its installer is available upon request at Customer Support (once you have purchased the license I would actually expect that it is shipped to you as part of all the software you have purchased).

In the case that you are a partner and have a active partner license to utilize the product, then you have to contact Customer Support for getting access to it.

Last note, the connector is only an ECL provider, you still will need to have a fully installed ADAM product, which is separately licensed and also a separate install (which you have to get from ADAM software of course.

Comment: Hi Bart, Actually it was no where mentioned that the connector is separately shipped on the sdltridionworld website and hence i was confused if i missing anything. ADAM we have already installed. Thanks, i will contact the customer support to get the connector

Comment: @rdhaundiyal I think you can generally conclude, if a product has its own publication in the documentation portal, then it will have a separate installer too. Also not all products are available fro download via SDL Tridion World, since they might require a special license or additional support, which is why in those cases your first point of contact is CS.